# How do I Focus a Camera in Windows Universal Apps?

Tags: c#, camera, uwp, autofocus

I am working with the Windows Universal Sample for OCR located here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/OCR/cs

Specifically the OcrCapturedImage.xaml.cs

It seems that the camera often becomes unfocused, blurry, and nowhere near as good quality as the native camera app. How can I set up autofocusing and/or tap to fix exposure?

What I have tried so far is looking at the other camera samples which help set resolution, but I cannot find anything about focus/exposure.

Update:

I think

```
await mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.FocusAsync();
```

and

```
await mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.ExposureControl.SetAutoAsync(true);
```

But this isn't working (does nothing-still blurry etc.) and could be built upon if someone knows how to tap a certain area and apply focus/exposure accordingly.

Native Camera:

[image]

App Camera:

[image]

Update based on answer:

I must have been putting my focus methods in the wrong spot because my original update code works. Sergi's also works. I want to used the tapped event in combination with it, something like this:

```
Point tapped=e.GetPosition(null); //Where e is TappedRoutedEventArgs from a tapped event method on my preview screen
await mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.RegionsOfInterestControl.ClearRegionsAsync();
await mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.RegionsOfInterestControl.SetRegionsAsync(new[] { new RegionOfInterest() { Bounds = new Rect(tapped.X, tapped.Y, 0.02, 0.02) } }); //Throws Parameter Incorrect
```

But it throws parameter incorrect. Also, How would I show the overlay a Rectangle on the preview screen, so the user knows how big the region of interest is?

This is a great link https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/CameraManualControls/cs/MainPage.Focus.xaml.cs

Comment: I don't see `CapturedImage.cs` in the page you're linking.

Comment: @Nick My bad OcrCapturedImage.xaml.cs. I updated

Comment: Could you please check whether focusing is available using these two properties `mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.Supported` and `mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.Focus.Capabilities.Supported`?

Comment: you could als try to [cofigure the focus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.devices.focuscontrol.configure.aspx), for example, `mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.Configure(new FocusSettings { Mode = FocusMode.Auto });` and then call 
`await mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.FocusAsync();`

Comment: @SergiiZhevzhyk Your last suggestion works. If you can add on to it by Focusing a certain point on the preview screen I would appreciate it. What I mean is on the native camera you can tap anywhere, and the focus and exposure will be set to that area

Comment: Could you pleas try to setup the [RegionOfInterestControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.media.devices.videodevicecontroller.regionsofinterestcontrol.aspx)? `The region of interest selects the area of preview that functions such as focus and exposure are computed over. This enables scenarios such as tap to focus.`.

Comment: @SergiiZhevzhyk Yes these look correct. If you write up an answer with both of these I will accept

Comment: @SethKitchen I've added the answer. I'm not able to test this code now so if you have any comments please let me know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Configuration of the auto focus using the [`Configure`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.devices.focuscontrol.configure.aspx) method of the `FocusControl` class.

```
mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.Configure(
    new FocusSettings { Mode = FocusMode.Auto });
await mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.FocusAsync();
```

In order to focus on a certain area, the [`RegionOfInterestControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.media.devices.videodevicecontroller.regionsofinterestcontrol.aspx) propery can be used. It has the [`SetRegionsAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn279071.aspx) method to add a collection of [`RegionOfInterest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.devices.regionofinterest.aspx) instances. `RegionOfInterest` has the [`Bounds`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.devices.regionofinterest.bounds.aspx) property which defines the region of focus. This example shows how to set the focus in the center:

```
// clear previous regions of interest
await mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.RegionOfInterestControl.ClearRegionsAsync();
// focus in the center of the screen
await mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.RegionOfInterestControl.SetRegionsAsync(
    new [] 
         { 
             new RegionOfInterest() {Bounds = new Rect(0.49,0.49,0.02,0.02) } 
         });
```

Comment: I have marked your answer as correct, but there are a couple things that could be added that I have listed in an update in my question. I will award the bounty if no other answers are better at the end of the time frame

Comment: I fixed parameter incorrect by adding AutoFocusEnabled=true, AutoExposureEnabled=true, AutoWhiteBalanceEnabled=true, BoundsNormalized=true, Type=RegionofInterestType.Unknown, and Weight=100 to my Roi instead of just Bounds. Now I get argument out of range. Either my point or size must be incorrect